# Refresh from a page to another page ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a tap and a page an when adding,

tab.ts

```
import { ProfileadminPage } from "../profileadmin/profileadmin.page";

  constructor(private profileadminPage: ProfileadminPage,)

      takePhoto() {
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
       mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    
      }
    
      
      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
       this.imgvi =  imagePath
       this.uploadimage()
        
      })
    }
    
    
    uploadimage(){
      let options: FileUploadOptions = {
             fileKey: "postedFile",
            fileName: ".JPG",
           mimeType: "image/jpeg",
            headers: {}
            
          }
        
        const apiurl= ...
     
       const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
         fileTransfer.upload(this.imgvi, apiurl,options)
           .then((data) => {
            
          if (data.response == '"ok"'){
          
        
        
         this.profileadminPage.phototab(this.ID)
         
          }else{
            
    
            
          }
           }, (err) => {
          
             alert(err)
        
            })
    }
    
    }
```

tab.html

```
<ion-tab-button class="ion-text-center text-align: center animate-me (click)="takePhoto()"></ion-tab-button>
```

So far, things are going very well

ProfileadminPage.html

```
 <ion-col  *ngFor="let photo of photos " >

 <img  src="{{ photo.url + photo.photo }}"/>
```

ProfileadminPage.ts

```
 phototab(id){

  this.ServicesService.getData("View_PhotoAdmin" + "?ID=" + id)
 .subscribe(res => {
  
  
this.photos =  res
    
 }, err => {
  
 });
 
 }
```

The images in the ProfileadminPage array have now been sent to the new data. I would like to refresh the page.
Now I want to refresh the page without using (windows.location.reload) just update new content

I want to refresh the page without using( wimdows.location.reload )

Only refresh ngFOr from tab page

It cannot be refleshed ngFor without using app life cyrcle ionic-

Comment: Please review your post. It is not fully clear what exactly is the structure of you application. From my point of you can use Observables or the page life cycle to update the parents page. But it depends a bit where you are handling the data.

Comment: I want to refresh the picture page with using page tab

Comment: The data is fetched from the server for the variable array photos and the code works correctly and the data is fetched in photos, but the page must be refreshed and I do not want to update the entire page

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved

First, a blank page is created with the name Update

You have modified a file
**app-routing.module.ts**

```
 {
    path: 'tabs/update',
    loadChildren: () => import('./update/update.module').then( m => m.UpdatePageModule)
  },
```

ProfileadminPage.ts

```
 async reload(url: string): Promise<boolean> {
      await this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/update', { skipLocationChange: true });
      return this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: Please who has the help? This solution I do not like